# How to find the optimal ${\bf Q}$ that maximizes $\left|{\bf I}+{\bf AQA^HB^{-1}}\right|$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenfunctions

I have the following question, which has stumped me for a long time.

${\max}_{\bf Q \succeq 0}~~~~{\rm det}\left({\bf I}+{\bf AQA^HB^{-1}}\right)$

s.t.$~~~{\rm Tr}\left({\bf Q}\right) \leq 1$.

where $\mathbf{B}=\operatorname{diag}\left[\mu_{1}, \cdots, \mu_{N}\right]$ is a diagonal matrix, and ${\bf A}$ is an arbitrary matrix.

Is there any possibility to find the optimal solution ${\bf Q}$ that has an explicit relationship with the diagonal elements of ${\bf B}$? (because $\left\{\mu_i\right\}$ are also variables.)

Answer (score 3):

At first glance I'd say that it looks difficult to find a closed form solution that depends directly on $B$. Using simple algebra, one can reshape the objective as:

${\rm det}\left({\bf I}+{\bf AQA^HB^{-1}}\right) = {\rm det}\left({\bf B}+{\bf AQA^H}\right) {\rm det}\left(\bf B^{-1}\right) = {\rm det}\left(\bf B^{-1/2}\right){\rm det}\left({\bf B}+{\bf AQA^H}\right) {\rm det}\left(\bf B^{-1/2}\right) = {\rm det}\left({\bf I}+{\bf B^{-1/2}AQA^HB^{-1/2}}\right)$

From here, write $C = B^{-1/2}A$, and write its SVD as $C = U_C \Sigma_C V_C^T$ and the SVD of $Q$ as $Q = U_Q \Sigma_Q U^T_Q$ (as Q is symmetric), then we have that the objective is:

${\rm det}\left( I + U_C \Sigma_C V_C^T U_Q \Sigma_Q U_Q^T V_C \Sigma_C U_C^T\right)$

We can take the orthonormal matrices $U_C$ out of the objective (as $I = U_C U_C^T$) and (and here I'd need a more formal proof) I'd expect the optimizer to have $U_Q = V_C$, as intuitively it makes sense that the determinant will be maximized when $Q$ is maximally aligned with $C$ in terms of singular vectors (with a similar logic to the [Von Neumann trace inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_inequality#Von_Neumann's_trace_inequality_and_related_results)). Then the objective would look like:

${\rm det}\left( I +  \Sigma_C  \Sigma_Q  \Sigma_C \right) = \prod_i^N \left(1+\sigma_i(C)^2 \cdot \sigma_i(Q)\right)$,

and I guess you could easily find a closed form solution for that under the constraint of $trace(Q) == 1$. But as you can see, the optimizer will depend on the singular values of $C=B^{-1/2}A$, so it won't be straightforward to relate the values of $B$ to the singular values of $C$, at least without assuming anything about $A$.

Is there anything else you can assume about $A$?

Comment: Is there possible to find a ${\bf Q}$ that achieves an upper bound of ${\rm det}\left({\bf I}+{\bf A}{\bf Q}{\bf A}^H{\bf B}^{-1}\right)$, then ${\bf Q}$ can be expressed in terms of ${\bf B}$ or the diagonal elements of ${\bf B}$?

Comment: I try to approximate ${\bf A}$ as a diagonal matrix.  But the difficulty is how to ensure the approximated ${\bf A}$  can achieve an upper bound of the objective function.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $C = B^{-1/2} A$ or am I missing something?

Comment: A comment regarding the reformulated objective function: After taking the logarithm, it can be solved by using the water filling algorithm, see, for example, https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/41756751.pdf.

Comment: @The Pheromone Kid  Yes, you are right,  ${\bf C}={\bf B}^{-1/2}{\bf A}$.

Comment: @The Pheromone Kid    Yes, the water-filling algorithm can be further applied if I can find the explicit relationship between ${\bf Q}$ and ${\bf B}$.

Comment: @Biel Roig-Solvas  Thanks, your analysis is absolutely correct! The challenging of the problem indeed lies in the singular value decomposition of ${\bf B}^{-1/2}{\bf A}$. Actually, ${\bf A}$ cannot be a diagonal matrix. But we can assume it is invertible. So, even if I assume ${\bf B}$ is diagonal here, it seems still cannot find the explicit relationship between ${\bf Q}$ and ${\bf B}$.

Comment: @ThePheromoneKid Yes, you're right, thanks for the edit!

Comment: @zhanghaiyang: Unless you somehow use the structure of $A$, I don't think there's a direct way to relate the entries of $B$ (or of $B^{-1/2}$) to the singular values of $C$. If your $A$ were to admit, for example, a factorization of the form $DQ$ by construction, with $D$ diagonal and $Q$ orthonormal, then you'd be able to get a closed form. But otherwise, for arbitrary $A$, I wouldn't hold out hope.

Comment: @ Biel Roig-Solvas Of course, if ${\bf A}={\bf DQ}$, then I can get the SVD decomposition result directly. But unfortunately, in my problem,  ${\bf A}$ is an arbitrary invertible matrix. Thanks.